# systemctl --user issue with dbus Failed to connect to bus: $DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS and $XDG_RUNTIME_DIR

Tags: systemd

I'm trying to set up systemd services for a user, but when I try to start the service, I get the following errror:

```bash
$ systemctl --user enable vdirsyncer.timer 
Failed to connect to bus: $DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS and 
$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not defined (consider using --machine=<user>@.host --user 
to connect to bus of other user)
```

I'm starting `dbus` in my `.xinitrc` with `export $(dbus-launch)`

```bash
$ echo $DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS 
unix:path=/tmp/dbus-3kIhCSkzBl,guid=40b6408906fa1337ba8283c06395fb80
    
$ echo $XDG_RUNTIME_DIR 
/run/user/1000 
    
$ systemctl --machine=$USER@$(hostname) --user  enable vdirsyncer.timer 
Cannot access user instance remotely.
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue. In my case, the problem was that I was using `su - <user>` or `sudo -u <user>` in first place. By default, these commands do not preserve environment variables like `$DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS` and `$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR`.

Using ssh to login solved the issue:
`ssh <user>@localhost`

Answer (score 0):

You're probably using `sudo -u $USER -i` or `su - $USER` which doesn't emulate a complete systemd session for the user.

You should first login to your new user with the command

`machinectl shell $USER@.host`

And then you can do

`systemctl --user enable vdirsyncer.timer`