# Allow cronjob to restart systemclt user unit

Tags: cron, d-bus, systemctl

I have a systemctl **user** unit:

```
[Unit]
Description=my app
Wants=network.target
After=syslog.target network-online.target

[Service]
Type=exec
ExecStart=/home/user/bin/myapp
StandardOutput=append:/home/user/log.log
StandardError=append:/home/user/log.log
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=10
KillMode=process

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

and I created this cronjob:

```
* *  *   *   *    /usr/bin/systemctl restart --user myapp.service
```

but it fails with the following error:

> Failed to connect to bus: $DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS and $XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not defined (consider using --machine=@.host --user to connect to bus of other user)

Typing the very same command from console it works fine, hence the problem is related tyo cron only.

I found also some other answers like [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/728274/systemctl-user-issue-with-dbus-failed-to-connect-to-bus-dbus-session-bus-add) but I don't understand how to set up those variables to be used with cron.

I'm using Ubuntu 22.04 by the way.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to linger your user:

`# loginctl enable-linger <user>`

Then you have to do a normal login to your `<user>` or do

`sudo machinectl shell <user>@.host`

Once in, copy those environment variables inside your crontab.

Your crontab should look like this:

```
DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/<uid>/bus
XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/<uid>
* *  *   *   *    /usr/bin/systemctl restart --user myapp.service
```

On the other hand, you have to change your target. User targets are not the same system's targets. To list available targets for your user do:

`$ systemctl --user --type=target`